# How to make proportions into percent for gglplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a bar graph with percents on the y-axis. This is my current code but it outputs a graph with proportions on the y-axis. How could I change that?

```
ggplot(data = Access.Use,aes(fill=Access)) +
 geom_bar(aes(x=Access, y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), fill="lightblue") + 
ylab("Proportion of Participants") + ylim(0,1) + 
xlab("Availability and Use") + theme_bw() + 
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

Comment: Try package `scales`, as in `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)` from the scales package.

```
Access.Use <- data.frame(Access=c("A", "B", "C", "A"))

ggplot(data = Access.Use) +
   geom_bar(aes(x=Access, y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), fill="lightblue") + 
   ylab("Proportion of Participants") + 
   xlab("Availability and Use") + 
   scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
   theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```